# Rails: how to check if params input's type is correct for database column type?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When building a query from user inputs, I want to check if the input's type is castable to rails column type. How to accomplish this?

Comment: See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html

Comment: @ArunKumar I probably wasn't very clear. Those are when you are creating or updating a model. I am trying to build dynamic queries from user inputs. So, when user submits an input with wrong type, it raises a database error